# Does $f(t)=\frac{t}{t^2+1}$ have a Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used GeoGebra to graph the function $f(t)=\frac{t}{t^2+1}$ and it seems continuous, furthermore $x^2+1$ will never be zero. It is also of exponential order because $e^t$ will grow faster than $f(t)$. Therefore $f(t)$ should have a Laplacee transform. However, I'm struggling finding this integral:

$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-st}\frac{t}{t^2+1}dt} 
$$

I used a couple of CAS programs and the output is the integral does not have a known antiderivative. So now I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if I made some mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has a Laplace transform, but whether that is an elementary function of $s$ is another question.

Comment: It is expressible in terms of the exponential integral (which is a non-elementary function). See, in particular, http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.7.E6

Comment: @Gary thanks, by the way that DLMF site is awesome!